# Syntax error while running an express file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting this error in the browser in my express app when i run the app:
The error is about localhost/:57 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'indic'

I have been trying to solve it for more than an hour but I couldn't solve it.
If somebody knows it then consider helping me.

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Connect to the MongoDB database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase')


const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, default: "Harry" },
  salary: Number,
  language: { type: String, required: true, default: "Python" },
  city: String,
  ismanager: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false }
}));


app.post('/createDatabase', async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({ name: 'Harry', salary: 4500000, language: 'Python', city: 'New York', ismanager: true });
  await newUser.save();
  res.send('Database created successfully');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
  <html>
  <head> 
      <title>Dummy maker</title>
      <style>
          * {
              padding: 0px;
              margin: 0px;
          }
  
          h1 {
              vertical-align: middle;
              height: 80px;
              text-align: center;
              background-color: rgb(240, 250, 215);
          }
  
          .data {
              height: 300px;
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: center;
          }
  
          button {
              background-color: antiquewhite;
              height: 200px;
              width: 400px;
              border-radius: 500px;
              margin-top: 300px;
          }
  
          button:active {
              height: 195px;
              width: 390px;
              /* background-color: gray; */
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
      <h1>The Dummy Data Maker</h1>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <div class="data">
          <div>
              <button class="button">Click me to, Generate the dummy data</button>
              <div class="indic"></div></div>
          <script>
  
          const button = document.querySelector("button")
          button.addEventListener("click", function () {
              document.querySelector(".indic").outerHTML = "<div class=\"indic\" style=\"margin-top: 300px; height: 50px; width: 400px; color: white; background-color: green; border-radius: 50px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;\">\nData Generated Successfully\n</div>"
              setTimeout(() => {
                  document.querySelector(".indic").outerHTML = "<div class=\"indic\"></div>"
              }, 2000);
  
              fetch('/createDatabase', { method: 'POST' })
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(message => alert(message));
            });
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
  `);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: How are you running this project ? Can you share your scripts in `package.json` ?